# XML Elements in Any Order, Some Required and Others Aren't

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to have a list of elements that are allowed in any order.  Some of the elements are required (min of 1, max of 1), some are optional with a maximum of one and some are optional with any number.  This is what I have and the XSD is valid, but when I go to validate an XML, the rules that I'm trying to implement aren't enforced.  For example, id is not made to be required.

```
<xsd:complexType name="feedType">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                The Atom feed construct is defined in section 4.1.1 of the format spec.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="author" type="atom:personType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="category" type="atom:categoryType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="contributor" type="atom:personType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="generator" type="atom:generatorType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="icon" type="atom:iconType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="id" type="atom:idType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="link" type="atom:linkType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="logo" type="atom:logoType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="rights" type="atom:textType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="subtitle" type="atom:textType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="title" type="atom:textType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="updated" type="atom:dateTimeType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="entry" type="atom:entryType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:choice>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="atom:commonAttributes"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`choice` only allows one of its child elements to be present in the XML graph.  It looks like you want to use `sequence` if your elements are always in the same order.  If the order is variable then you should use `all` and wrap all elements that have `maxOccurs="unbounded"` in a containing list element, because `all` only allows 1 or zero occurrences of its child elements.

EDIT:

And you should remove the minOccurs & maxOccurs from the choice element.  This only allows you to enforce 3 choices, but doesn't allow you specify what choices they are (including repeating the same element multiple times).  I don't know what exactly you're trying to enforce, but it won't be effectively enforced that way.

EDIT 2:

You can create list wrappers as follows (using the link element as an example):

```
<xs:element name="linkList" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="link" type="atom:linkType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

and in the xml document you would (for example) nest your link elements in the linkList:

Old:

```
<other elements...>
<id>...</id>
<link>...</link>
<link>...</link>
<logo>...</logo>
<other elements...>
```

New:

```
<other elements...>
<id>...</id>
<linkList>
  <link>...</link>
  <link>...</link>
</linkList>
<logo>...</logo>
<other elements...>
```

Comment: It seems that the only elements allowed under xsd:all are annotation and element so I'm not sure how I would wrap the maxOccurs="unbounded" elements.

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that I don't have control of the XML structured and really we don't have the equivalent of a LinkedList container element.  Each of those "link" elements are at the same level as id.  This is the Atom standard.  There is no official XSD and we're trying to create one for our own use but still follow the Atom standard.

Comment: Then you need to use a sequence, which means that the element order will need to remain constant in the XML doc's.

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid as I wanted the elements to be able to be in any order, just as the standard allows.  Maybe this is a limitation of XSD that I can't achieve all goals at the same time.

Comment: Yes, you either constrain your element order or have list wrapping elements.  The XSD is this way because if, within a given containing element, you have the ability to have multiple elements of the same type AND no set order for your elements you could disperse collections of a single element type throughout that level, interspersed with elements of other types.  This would make it ambiguous as to whether the intention is to have a single or multiple collections of a given type.

Answer (score 13):

I just ran into the same problem and had a look at what they did in the [XHTML XSD](http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd). Same situation there inside `head`: `title` is required, `base` is optional, and then there's an arbitrary number of `script`, `style`, `meta`, `link` and `object` elements allowed.

Here's what they did: First, they grouped the optional elements that may occur more than once:

```
  <xs:group name="head.misc">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="script"/>
        <xs:element ref="style"/>
        <xs:element ref="meta"/>
        <xs:element ref="link"/>
        <xs:element ref="object"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
```

Then they referenced this group in the actual `head` definition:

```
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:group ref="head.misc"/>
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="title"/>
        <xs:group ref="head.misc"/>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
          <xs:element ref="base"/>
          <xs:group ref="head.misc"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="base"/>
        <xs:group ref="head.misc"/>
        <xs:element ref="title"/>
        <xs:group ref="head.misc"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:sequence>
```

This is a bit tricky. Written as regex-like pseudo code, the above looks something like this:

```
misc=(script|style|meta|link|object)*
head=${misc}(title${misc}(base${misc})?|base${misc}title${misc})
```

So, technically it works.

However, this requires putting all possible permutations of the mandatory and optional elements (with the misc stuff in between) inside `choice`. With `n` elements, that's `n!` child nodes. So for XHTML with `n=2` they ended up with `n!=2`. In your case with `n=8`, it's going to be `n!=40320`.

FWIW, here's the algorithm to generate your XSD:

```js
result = '<xs:group name="misc"><xs:sequence><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">'
forall(optionalArbitraryCountElements as element)
    result += '<xs:element ref="' + element.name + '"/>'
result += '</xs:choice></xs:sequence></xs:group>'

result += '<xs:complexType name="feedType"><xs:sequence><xs:group ref="misc"/><xs:choice>'
permutations = getAllPermutations(mandatoryElements + optionalOnceElements)
foreach (permutations as p)
    result += '<xs:sequence>'
    foreach (p as element)
        if (element.isOptional)
            result += '<xs:sequence minOccurs="0">'
        result += '<xs:element ref="' + element.name + '"/><xs:group ref="misc"/>'
        if (element.isOptional)
            result += '</xs:sequence>'
    result += '</xs:sequence>'
result += '</xs:choice></xs:sequence></xs:complexType>'

return result
```

Comment: +1, I just needed the elements that can repeat any number of times, so I jsut used `<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">` instead of `<xs:all>`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, don't do that when using XSD. It is not designed for a use case like this.

You can validate with [RelaxNG](http://relaxng.org/) instead, using its unordered operation, or if you have a partner who requires an XSD then enforce an arbitrary order.

The schema for atom feeds given in [RFC4287](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287#section-4.1.1) uses RelaxNG for this reason:

```
   atomFeed =
      element atom:feed {
         atomCommonAttributes,
         (atomAuthor*
          & atomCategory*
          & atomContributor*
          & atomGenerator?
          & atomIcon?
          & atomId
          & atomLink*
          & atomLogo?
          & atomRights?
          & atomSubtitle?
          & atomTitle
          & atomUpdated
          & extensionElement*),
         atomEntry*
      }
```

See [Principles of XML design: When the order of XML elements matters](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-eleord/) for further discussion of when to enforce order in XML