# XSD Validation Error : cos-all-limited.1.2: An 'all' model group must appear in a particle with

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, xerces

I have and XSD which gives the following error during the schema generation.

```
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/Basil/Projects/myproducts.xsd; lineNumber: 577; columnNumber: 50; cos-all-limited.1.2: An 'all' model group must appear in a particle with '{'min occurs'}' = '{'max occurs'}' = 1, and that particle must be part of a pair which constitutes the '{'content type'}' of a complex type definition.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4124)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:588)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:555)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:521)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:240)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.SchemaConstraintChecker.check(SchemaConstraintChecker.java:101)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:357)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:167)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:113)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:313)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractXjcMojo.execute(AbstractXjcMojo.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
```

The relevant XSD is pasted below. I'm unable to understand what the actual error is. Error is on the third line from end. Please help.

```
<xs:group name="prodVar">
  <xs:all>
     <xs:element name="prodVar" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="varName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
              <xs:element ref="skuList" />
              <xs:element name="vStory" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element ref="attList" />
           </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
     <xs:element name="colorSwatchList" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:element name="colorSwatch" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                 <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                       <xs:element name="swatchName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                       <xs:element name="swatchHeight" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                       <xs:element name="swatchWidth" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                       <xs:element name="colorName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                       <xs:element name="mainImageHeight" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                       <xs:element name="mainImageWidth" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                       <xs:element name="mainImageName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                 </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
           </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
  </xs:all>
</xs:group>

<!--lot of other stuff -->

<xs:element name="prodVarList" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:complexType> <!-- ERROR HERE -->
        <xs:group ref="prodVar" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just get rid of `maxOccurs="unbounded"` in `<xs:group ref="prodVar" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />`

In XSD 1.0, an `xs:all` cannot repeat (here indirectly, some may say 'nice try!'), nor any particle under `xs:all`, nor can it be nested under any other compositor.

Comment: See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902485/xml-elements-in-any-order-some-required-and-others-arent/14843147#comment63268281_14843147) on [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14843147/5445670) to [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10902485/5445670) for a replacement.